# Exceptions for Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting several unhandled exceptions while using Code First Migrations of Entity Framework 4.3.

The database context:

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }

   public MyAppContext()
   { }
}
```

The entity:

```
public class Branch : IEntity<Guid>
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
 }
```

The database initializer:

```
public class MyAppInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<MyAppContext>
{
   protected override void Seed(MyAppContext context)
   {
      context.Branches.Add(new Branch() { Id = branchId, Name = "Acme", Description = "Acme", Active = true });
      context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

I installed Entity Framework 4.3 to my DAL project and MVC project using:

> Install-Package EntityFramework

I have set the MVC project as the startup project and executed the following command to the DAL project with the database context and initializer:

> PM> Enable-Migrations -Verbose
>
> Using NuGet project 'Ckms.KeyManagement.Managers'. 
>   Error while searching for context type (specify -Verbose to see exception details).
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetContextTypes()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsCommands.FindContextToEnable()
>   Edit the generated Configuration class to specify the context to
>   enable migrations for. 
>   Code First Migrations enabled for project Ckms.KeyManagement.Managers.

A DbMigrationsConfiguration child class is added to the DAL project. If I add the type of the DbContext manually and enable Automatic Migrations:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyAppContext>
{
   public Configuration()
   {
      AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
   }

   protected override void Seed(MyAppContext context)
   { }
}
```

These exceptions are thrown for the Add-Migration and Update-Database commands:

> PM> Add-Migration TestEFMigrationsColumn -Verbose
>
> Using NuGet project
>   'Ckms.KeyManagement.Managers'. Using StartUp project ''.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers,
>   Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ComMethod.InvokeMethod(PSMethod method,
>   Object[] arguments) Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Update-Database:

> PM> Update-Database -Verbose
>
> Using NuGet project
>   'Ckms.KeyManagement.Managers'. Using StartUp project ''.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: The
>   parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057
>   (E_INVALIDARG))    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers,
>   Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)    at
>   System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags
>   bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[]
>   namedParams)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ComMethod.InvokeMethod(PSMethod method,
>   Object[] arguments) Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.

Any ideas? The error messages are not really helpful. I have tried the Nuget commands with and without an existing database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using separate library for data access you  need to provide it name when running query:

*Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName "Your DAL Project" MyNewMigration*

*Update-Database -StartUpProjectName "Your DAL Project" -Verbose*

Comment: That does not solve it I am afraid. If I add the StartUpProjectName argument to the command, the following error is raised: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.

Comment: do you have proper settings in dll config. I mean config section, sql connection etc.

Comment: That's it! I had to add the sql connection to the app.config of the DAL dll. Note that the -StartupProjectName argument must point to the MVC/ui project instead of the DAL project. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AlexandervanTrijffel: If this answer solved the problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the votes number.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, could you please explain better how do you solve it? What and where have you added a SQL connection??

Answer (score 4):

```
add-migration -Name First -ProjectName DbSet.Framework -StartUpProjectName CodeFirstConsole
```

First: Name of Migration

Dbset.Framework: Project where dbContext and other classes

CodeFirstConsole: Start Up project (could be your web, windows or console app)

Answer (score 3):

For System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) adding -projectname and startupprojectname did not help.

Setting the PackageManager Console's "Default Project" Dropdown to point to the Library (in my case) where I wanted the "Migration folder" and its expected contents to be was the only way to get this running from a multiproject solution.

Comment: Paul, Could you expand this a bit?  I'm also not able to add -projectname and startupprojectname and get it to work.  Where do you set the "default project" (in using VS2013 I didn't see that).

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. Found out that if anything is wrong with the config files this error comes up. I had duplicate tags in web.config and removing these solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had solve this problem only by changing the **name** used in connection string.

```
<add name="abcd" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

And I use connectionStrings after closing tag of the

```
appSettings
```

and just before starting tag of

```
system.web
```

Make sure that **name** that you use in `connectionString` not used in other connections.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem , solved by removing `<globalization>` from web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having two connection strings in your web. Config files. Just delete one